# 404 Not Found nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu) error when trying to download eclipse for 32 bits windows

Tags: eclipse, download, 32-bit

I am trying to download eclipse IDE for JAVA EE developpers and for windows 32 bits from here:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR2/eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32.zip

Click there is returning this error :

> 404 not found nginx/1.14.0 (ubuntu)

and I can not download the needed zip file.

What's the reasan and how can I solve this issue, please ?

Comment: Eclipse Helios (3.6) is 9 years old, the last 32 bit Eclipse is Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9). The [Eclipse Archive Site](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) has all the old releases

Comment: @greg-449 I am lookin to download eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32.zip et not helios

Comment: Your download URL is for Helios. Luna (4.4) is still 5 years old.

Comment: @Imed Eclipse Luna (4.4) is 5 years old and therefore also moved to the archive. Use Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) if and only if you have a 32 bit Java and not being able to install 64 bit Java, otherwise use Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12).